# assign a binary output for each id that has variables of two dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
id  days test result    id  output 
1   1    1              1   1
1   2    0              2   0
1   3    0              3   1
1   4    1                  
1   5    1                  
2   1    1                  
2   2    0                  
2   3    0                  
3   1    1                  
3   2    1                  
3   3    1                  
3   4    1
```

I am a beginner, using Jupter Notebook, pandas. I'm wondering how can I assign a binary output for each id; out put `1` if get a test result `1` after `day1`, else `0`.

The senario is that every person get a test on each day. Test result would be `1` or `0`.
If anyone still get a test result of `1` after `day1`, he would be `1` in final output. If he get `0` after `day1`, he would be `0`.

days are differnt for each id.

What I try:

```
df['output'] = np.where((df.test result=1)&(df.days>1)), '1', '0').
```

Comment: What are your constraints to assign the binary output? Can you be more clear to your question /

Comment: out put 1 if get a test result gives 1 after day1, else 0.

Comment: I'm a bit confused after reading the input and the desired output. Have you switched the days column with id column in your "desired output"?

Comment: Do you need pandas solution? Is there always day1 per group? Days are always sorted?

Comment: @jezrael , yes, pandas solution, aways day1 per group and days always sorted.

Comment: Super, can you add some code, what you try (not problem if not working) to question?

Comment: I have totally no idea. what I have tried is that df['output'] = np.where((df.test result=1)&(df.days>1)), '1', '0').   but this only give output for every rows.

Comment: @Yuuu - Added your code to question, also added answer. please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with custom lambda function for test all values with omit first (day1) with [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) and last cast `True/False` to `1/0`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('id')['test'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[1:].any()).astype(int).reset_index()
print (df1)
   id  test
0   1     1
1   2     0
2   3     1
```

For check selections per groups:

```
df1 = df.groupby('id')['test'].agg(lambda x: print(x.iloc[1:]))
print (df1)
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
Name: test, dtype: int64
6    0
7    0
Name: test, dtype: int64
9     1
10    1
11    1
Name: test, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helps. Can you explain that code a little bit? I dont really understandthe part lambda x: x.iloc[1:].any()

Comment: I got it. I just see ur explaination is above the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know for each id and day, if there are 1's for that id after that day (and not just for after the first day), you can use this vectorize solution:

```
data = data.sort_values(['id', 'days']) # can pass if you know the data is sorted by id & days
data['output'] = 0
for i in range(1, max(data['days'])):
    data['output'] = 1 * ((data['output'] == 1) | \
                     ((data['id'] == data['id'].shift(-i)) & (data['test'].shift(-i) == 1)))
```